# Simple java code does not compile - "Create class 'Object' in type 'java.lang'"

Tags: java, eclipse, object, compiler-errors

The following code doesn't compile (using eclipse Luna):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.lang.Object Object = new java.lang.Object(); // Error line
        System.out.println(Object.class);
    }
}

class java {
    static lang lang;
}

class lang {
    static Object Object;
}

class Object {
    static java java;
}
```

Eclipse auto-suggests that I  "Create class 'Object' in type 'java.lang'"...

(I *DO* have JRE in build path).

So, what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**

Error is in both decleration and instantiation statments.

**EDIT 2:**

Instantiating `java` still produces same error:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java java = new java();
        java.lang.Object Object = new java.lang.Object();
        System.out.println(Object.class);
    }
}

class java {
    static lang lang = new lang();
}

class lang {
    static Object Object = new Object();
}

class Object {
    static java java = new java();
}
```

Comment: Well.. why not? What's wrong with declaring a `java.lang.Object` instance?

Comment: Erase the classes `java`, `lang`, and `Object` at the bottom -- you are confused -- those are not needed.

Comment: `java` and `lang` are packages. And `Object` already exists as a class. I think you need to learn more about how classes and objects work in Java.

Comment: I know there are packages, but I can still declare a class name to be identical to a package name, can't I?

Comment: Please don't use `Object` with a capital `O` as a variable name.  You're asking for all sorts of bad things to happen if you do that.

Comment: @Elist You don't need to define an `Object` class. And you don't need the `java.lang`, simply `Object obj = new Object();`.

Comment: I don't *need* to, But I *want* to.

Comment: @Elist none of the static variables are defined, is this intended? I have a solution that compiles with an exception as intended.

Comment: @Compass - Can you post it?

Comment: @Elist Why do you want to? You are asking for major issues here. Also, your static variables in your classes are all null. That could cause issues. And your classes are circular. `java` contains `lang` contains `Object` contains `java` contains `lang` ... and on and on. That could also cause issues. What exactly are you trying to do here? We can help better if we know your goal.

Comment: you don't need to create java and lang as classes

Comment: vote to close since the OP appears to be a troll

Comment: @Ali I don't *need* to, But I *want* to. these are not reserved words or class names duplication, or is it?

Comment: @Elist - that's fine, but see my answer below

Comment: No trolling. Only pointing out an interesting issue in java's spec...

Comment: @Elist Then you should have phrased your question that way. You would have gotten much better responses if people knew you were just exploring some oddities about the Java language.

Comment: Tried that once. Not true. Unfotunately, in SO you get voted down for nice puzzeles like this one, even if you phrased your question as a puzzle...

Comment: Perhaps you're not trolling *per se*, but I can only conclude that your question is posed in bad faith.  You are not looking for an answer, you are making a statement.  For the record, however, I do not find it troublesome or even very interesting that Java refuses to compile your code, because the code is erroneous.

Comment: I am making a statement, a statement I think could be an excelent openning for an artical about java, for instance. I thing such questions make people think and see programming language in a broader view. But I guess next time I should share my thoughts in other forums. Lesson learned...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that by defining a class called `java`, you've changed the meaning of `java.lang.Object` - so the compiler now sees this as something that's semantically incorrect, instead of seeing it as the name of the `java.lang.Object` class.

Don't make a class called `java`.  It breaks everything.

Comment: It does, doesn't it? :0

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Java's standard naming conventions, i.e. capitalize classes and don't capitalize variable names.
2. `java.lang.Object` already exists, so there's no need to write

   ```
   class java {
       static lang lang;
   }

   class lang {
       static Object Object;
   }

   class Object {
       static java java;
   }
   ```
3. `java.lang` is implicitly imported, so you don't need to say

   ```
   java.lang.Object object = new java.lang.Object();
   ```

   You can just say

   ```
   Object object = new Object();
   ```

The final code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = new Object();
        System.out.println(object.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate `java` before you can access its children in this case, resulting in something less elegant.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object Object = (new java()).lang.Object; // instantiate java, THEN call lang.Object
    System.out.println(Object.getClass());
}
```

This results in:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Test.main(Test.java:4)

Which is expected because `lang` is `null` within `java` as you haven't declared an initial value for the static `lang`.

Comment: @Elist and my head exploded.

Answer (score 0):

java is defined as a class in the local scope, which takes precedence over the globally defined java package. So, when your code refers to java.lang.Object, the compiler will understand this as a reference to the static Object property of the lang class. Object being an "object" and not a type, your syntax is  illegal

```
java.lang.Object Object = new java.lang.Object();  //this is illegal because java.lang.Object is an object, not a type

Object o = java.lang.Object; //this is legal because you're just creating a reference to an object
```

Comment: This means that I can never declare an Object (I mean the regular - well-known Object) in this scope... Don't you find it bothering?

Comment: @Elist In my 5 years of enterprise java programming, no. I've never needed to do that. You have full control over what you name local variables, so there is room to respect the names used by the libraries that are making your code work :)

Comment: @AliCheaito Your answer is wrong. `java.lang.Object Object = new java.lang.Object();` is perfectly valid Java by itself; the only reason it doesn't compile is that @Elist is name-shadowing `java` with his class. That's a very bad idea. `Object o = java.lang.Object;` is **not** valid Java, unless you have the weird code that @Elist added. Try both in your compiler without @Elist's code and you'll see that the first line is valid and the second line is not.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt My answer is perfectly fine, given that it's completely based on the code that Elist provided. In fact, I explained the "name-shadowing" effect in my answer without using the fancy term. I never said that java.lang.Object Object = new java.lang.Object(); is "not perfectly valid Java by itself", I simply explained why it doesn't work in the given code. Please understand the answer before down voting.